# Shopee Open Platform API always response "Invalid token"

Tags: hex, authorization, token, sha256

I'm sorry in advance if something bring you here and I talk about a platform that's not really well-known over the world despite featuring a well-known person dancing in their commercial.

It's Shopee Open Platform API I talk about. I was trying to follow very properly their instruction here.

> https://open.shopee.com/documents?module=63&type=2&id=51

But stuck instantly at step 5 : Shop Authorization. First, I've been given a test partner id, a test key, and I need to set manually the test redirect URL. I have to generate authorization token from all given information. Firstly I need to create a token base string by concatenating the test key with URI component encoded string of the URL. It turns into something like this.

> 9b754aca01a5d719cb70c5778294dae6ff90fcc68c82908ee480a36ff901d181https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unwelldocumented.com

To generate the authorization token, it says I need to do `hexencode(sha256(token_base_string))`. It returned a very long integer.

> 32373935663639356636346266303137613465396239383361373334646133656530313333393762636138396364663037366566313366313436316534303761

So I just assumed everything is fine and that is the authorization token. But when I send this...

> https://partner.uat.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/shop/auth_partner?id=(test_partner_id)&token=(authorization_token)&redirect=(test_redirect_URL)

... suddenly I get this

```
{
    "error": "error_auth",
    "msg": "Invalid token",
    "request_id": "30a4b6b0074541bdd88260a33f155ca6"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you have to understand that SHA256 is an Encryption hash function. Please research more on SHA256 on your specific language.
For this very specific case, your SHA256 token should be as below.

Before SHA256:

9b754aca01a5d719cb70c5778294dae6ff90fcc68c82908ee480a36ff901d181https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unwelldocumented.com

After SHA256:

2795f695f64bf017a4e9b983a734da3ee013397bca89cdf076ef13f1461e407a

The rest of your steps seems correct.

Comment: thank you sir. very much appreciate to get an answer for a question that unlikely to get an answer. I'm gonna test it first and will mark it if working. thanks again

Comment: ok so right after sha256 which I've already did and got the same string as in your answer,  is that already the auth token? no need to hexencode it? because the auth token string in my question is the hexencoded one

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Go ahead and try it out first and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: to mr https://stackoverflow.com/users/9372413/arul. please provide a link for me to message you